# Java LinkedList Order

Tags: java

I was going through Java LinkedList add with position method and tried different combinations. I ended up getting an order which I'm not able to understand.

```
list.add(new Picholine());
list.add(1, new Golden());
list.add(0, new Kalamata());
```

Expected output:

```
Kalamata
Golden
Picholine
```

Actual output:

```
Kalamata
Picholine
Golden
```

Comment: Output seems reasonable to me. Why do you expect your expected output?

Comment: Actual output is reasonable with your. Either you should change your expected output or code.

Comment: Pay attention to the point `Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).`

Comment: @JoeC why are you telling them to use a debugger ? The question is clear and concise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `list.add(new Picholine())` the list looks like this:

```
[Picholine]
```

When you call `list.add(1, new Golden())` the list inserts a `Golden` at the `1` index giving:

```
[Picholine, Golden]
```

Finally when we call `list.add(0, new Kalamata())` a new `Kalamata` instance is placed at the `0` index (the start of the list), giving our final list:

```
[Kalamata, Picholine, Golden]
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 3):

Java lists are indexed from 0.

You:

- Add `Picholine` at the end (index 0)

  - You have `{ Picholine }`
- Add `Golden` at index 1 of the above list

  - You now have `{ Picholine, Golden }`
- Add `Kalamata` at index 0 of the new list

  - You end up with `{ Kalamata, Picholine, Golden }`